# Setting up Spring Boot Repository Test Fails on Autowired Repo Bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing

I have a `Service` in my Spring Boot 3.1 project which acts similar to a repository. I wrote it as a service because my query needs to be hibernate native (HQL). I am now trying to test via a Integration test. I have been referring to this [resource](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-data-jpa-test/).

The `Service` (i.e. repo) looks like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomContosoRepository implements CustomContosoService {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public ContosoDetailsDto customQueryGetContosoDetails(Long id) {
    return (ContosoDetailsDto) entityManager.createQuery(
                    "SELECT NEW com.nz.contoso.view.ContosoDetailsDto(Hibernate HQL query here")
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

Then I have tried to setup Test class with empty method and a connection to a test container database:

```
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "spring.test.database.replace=none",
    "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:mysql:8.1.0:///test?TC_REUSABLE=true"
})

public class CustomContosoRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private CustomContosoRepository customContosoRepository;

@Test
@Sql("/data-custom.sql")
void shouldReturnReturnContosoDetalisDto() {

}
```

The error when running the test:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.nz.contoso.repository.CustomContosoRepositoryTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customContosoRepository': No qualifying bean of type 'com.nz.contoso.repository.CustomContosoRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

This error seems odd since I am wiring in `CustomContosoRepository` but I presume it is due to the lack of `@Repository` - and because it is a class not a interface extending JPA?

Note the connection to the test db container is already setup and running.

How can I setup the infrastructure for this test?

Answer (score 1):

`@DataJpaTest` does not scan the `CustomContosoRepository` .

Simply add a test config in your tests like this.

```java
//...
public class CustomContosoRepositoryTest {


   
     @TestConfiguration
     @Import(CustomContosoRepository.class)
     static class TestConfig{} // must a static class.

     //...

}
```

An test configuration sample from my example project, https://github.com/hantsy/spring6-sandbox/blob/master/boot/src/test/java/com/example/demo/domain/PostRepositoryTest.java#L33-L36

Comment: This is very different to the setup shown in the link at the top of my Question. Are you still using `@DataJpaTest` ? What about `@Test` on the method?

Comment: yes, only adding the testconfiguration class is enough, no changes for others.

Comment: And you have a inner class?

Comment: I get a IDE error on the brackets in TestConfig() method saying `Record header declared for non-record`

Comment: Remove the `()` constructor here, I am using Kotlin in daily work. And always try to add constructor in the class declaration.

Comment: Ok - removed the () but now I cant run the class - Intellij provides no option to run this test?

Comment: Try to refresh your IDE and rebuild the project. Or share your code sample via Github, it is easier to find the issue directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255479/discussion-between-radika-moonesinghe-and-hantsy).

Answer (score 1):

The source of this error was that the `CustomContosoRespository` really isn't a repository at all but a Class annotated with `@Service`. This was done because I was using a native hibernate query with HQL.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomContosoRepository implements CustomContosoService {
```

The fix was to convert the query to JPQL and put it inside a `@Repository` class in the usual way:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomContosoRepository extends JpaRepository<Contoso, Long> {
```

Comment: There is no difference between `@Service` and `@Repository`, both are derived from `@Compoennt`. In Spring Boot applications, no need `@Repository` annotation when extending from a `JpaReposiotry`.